# reading image filename from csv for renderImage src in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to display images in my shiny R app. I have different images for each instance in the dataset, all the images are in png format in the www folder.

I think I am having difficulty in constructing the images filepath for the src argument in the renderImage method, the name of the image file is in the 21st column of the dataframe. Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

df<-read.csv("data2.csv",header = T)


ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
# Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
fluidRow(
  box(
    title = "Controls", solidHeader = TRUE, status="primary",collapsible = TRUE,
    sliderInput("num", "Select Asset Number:", min(df[,1]), max(df[,1]), 1,step = 1),
    actionButton("but1","Go")
  ),
  box(
    imageOutput("myimage",width=300,height=300)
  )
)

)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

values<-reactiveValues(data = NULL)


observeEvent(input$but1, {
dataset<- data.frame(df)
values$data<- dataset
temp <- values$data[input$num, ]
values$data <- temp
})


output$myimage<- renderImage({
path<-file.path("www/",values$data[21],".png")

return(list(src = path, 
contentType = "image/png"))

},
deleteFile = FALSE
)



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks alot

Comment: My understanding is that you don't need the `www/` part if your image is under `www`